# Syntax highlighting in emacs. Marking different data types with different colours

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

In Emacs, is it possible to mark all variables of different data types with different colors? e.g. if I have the following variables in C/C++ my program

```
int i,j;
float g,h;
char a,b;
```

Then *throughout* the source code i and j would be marked as red, g and h as green, a and b as blue.

I am not sure how useful this will be in future, but I feel it would help me while reading code, 
and be a good alternative to the Hungarian notation(not that I use this notation :D).

Comment: With the normal emacs C mode this would be very nontrivial--you would need to actually parse the file to get this information where you currently just use regular expressions for highlighting. I would check out the ["Semantic Bovinator"](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SemanticBovinator) for parsing C/C++ files and work from there.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at [highlight-symbol](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightSymbol). It highlights all occurrences of the symbol at point, and you can have several symbols highlighted simultaneously (in different colors). Not exactly what you're asking for, but it helps reading code in a similar fashion.

Comment: Another not-exactly comment: Regexp matching is probably not sufficient for this, but it might get you part of the way. An easy and interactive way to tweak regexp matching is to use `C-M-s`.  See also library [`highlight.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary).

Comment: This would seem to do the trick: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/highlight-chars.el

Answer (score 4):

No. Emacs has no idea about the type of a specific expression; doing this would be tantamount to writing a significant part of a `C` compiler in `ELisp`.

However, there is a light at the end of the tunnel.

E.g., if you edit `OCaml` code using `tuareg-mode`, you can ask Emacs about the type of any expression because the `ocaml` compiler provides that information; thus you should be able to ask it to highlight variables by type. This is the path to follow.

Alas, `gcc` does not provide that information; however, its extension[`gccxml`](http://www.gccxml.org/) does.

Also, other `C` compilers, e.g., [`clang`](http://clang.llvm.org), provide that information out of the box, and there is a new file [`semantic-clang.el`](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena.mit.edu/software/matlab_v8.0/newemacs/cedet/semantic/bovine/semantic-clang.el) which relies on those features (although for completion only, not for syntax highlighting).

So, nothing out of the box for you here, but if you are willing to use `clang` instead of `gcc` and contribute to the `CEDET` development, you might get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to selectively assign a given color to a given variable in emacs (or just for one given program).
However, if it's just *syntax highlighting* you are looking for, of course, emacs will highlight most languages, and you can even create syntax highlighting for languages emacs would not know about.
Ex. Smali: https://github.com/strazzere/Emacs-Smali